# PHP7 does not compile on arm64 (OrangePI PC2)

Tags: php, arm64

I am trying to write a PHP program which requires pthreads on an Orange PI PC2. pthreads requires zts, which is not normally included in PHP but easy to add during build time.

Unfortunately, I get the following error when trying to build PHP 7. I've tried 7.0.14 and 7.1.  It all works perfect on a raspberry pi (not 64 bit). Does anyone know how to fix this error?

```
orangepi@Orangepi:~/php-7.1.0$ make -j2
/bin/bash /home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/libtool --silent --preserve-dup-deps --mode=compile /home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/meta_ccld -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -Iext/opcache/ -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/ext/opcache/ -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/include -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/main -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0 -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/ext/sqlite3/libsqlite -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/TSRM -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/Zend  -D_REENTRANT  -I/usr/include -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -pthread -DZTS -DZEND_SIGNALS    -c /home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/ext/opcache/ZendAccelerator.c -o ext/opcache/ZendAccelerator.lo 
/bin/bash /home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/libtool --silent --preserve-dup-deps --mode=compile /home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/meta_ccld -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -Iext/opcache/ -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/ext/opcache/ -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/include -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/main -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0 -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/ext/sqlite3/libsqlite -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/TSRM -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/Zend  -D_REENTRANT  -I/usr/include -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -pthread -DZTS -DZEND_SIGNALS    -c /home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_blacklist.c -o ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_blacklist.lo 
mkdir: cannot create directory 'ext/opcache/.libs': File exists
/bin/bash /home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/libtool --silent --preserve-dup-deps --mode=compile /home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/meta_ccld -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -Iext/opcache/ -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/ext/opcache/ -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/include -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/main -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0 -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/ext/sqlite3/libsqlite -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/TSRM -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/Zend  -D_REENTRANT  -I/usr/include -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -pthread -DZTS -DZEND_SIGNALS    -c /home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_debug.c -o ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_debug.lo 
/bin/bash /home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/libtool --silent --preserve-dup-deps --mode=compile /home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/meta_ccld -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -Iext/opcache/ -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/ext/opcache/ -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/include -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/main -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0 -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/ext/sqlite3/libsqlite -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/TSRM -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/Zend  -D_REENTRANT  -I/usr/include -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -pthread -DZTS -DZEND_SIGNALS    -c /home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_hash.c -o ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_hash.lo 
/bin/bash /home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/libtool --silent --preserve-dup-deps --mode=compile /home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/meta_ccld -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -Iext/opcache/ -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/ext/opcache/ -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/include -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/main -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0 -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/ext/sqlite3/libsqlite -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/TSRM -I/home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/Zend  -D_REENTRANT  -I/usr/include -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -pthread -DZTS -DZEND_SIGNALS    -c /home/orangepi/php-7.1.0/ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_module.c -o ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_module.lo 
/tmp/ccuWeYfe.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccuWeYfe.s:951: Error: operand 3 should be an integer register -- `mul x1,x1,1048576'
/tmp/ccuWeYfe.s:952: Error: operand 3 should be an integer register -- `smulh x0,x1,1048576'
Makefile:1000: recipe for target 'ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_module.lo' failed
make: *** [ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_module.lo] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I've searched everywhere, and only found a similar documented [issue](https://github.com/kyrofa/owncloud-snap/issues/64), but still cannot get past this.

Comment: FYI - After 2 days of this stupid issue, I got passed it by removing ext/opcache and a '/buildconf --force'. This, clearly removes opcache which might cause performance issues but my purpose is CLI only. All is working, however, I'd love to see if there is a real fix.

Comment: I maintain the nextcloud snap (to which you linked) and I'm getting the same with both 7.0.14 and 7.1. We're stuck on 7.0.12. I've not had any luck getting around it, either.

Comment: I [logged a bug against PHP](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73898), maybe they have some advice.

Answer (score 2):

[Bug #73898](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73898), this has been fixed in both 7.0.15 and 7.1.1 (I just verified both).